# Issue in xml layout

Tags: android, xml

[image]

I want to design this dailog box in xml. I am beginner in android. I search for this dailog box but could not find. how could i design this. please help me.

Comment: You can design the dialog box in a xml and then can inflate the layout into a dialog popup. You can find a simple implementation here https://github.com/arshadkazmi42/android-contacts-scifiui/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kaspat/contacts/utils/Popups.java#L21

Comment: That's not easy, you might need to render the line between the two items on a canvas.